# How to extract body from request with express in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node.Js and `express` framework for my application.

I build HTML forms and upon submitting I'm not able to receive my `form` data on API request.

My HTML:

```html
<form method="post" action="/create">
    <input type="text" name="user.name" />
    <input type="text" name="user.email" />
    <input type="text" name="user.address.city" />
    <input type="text" name="user.address.land" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JSON object should been obtained at my API:

```
{
   "user": {
      "name": "toto",
      "email": "toto@mail.com",
      "address": {
         "city": "yyyyy",
         "land": "zzzz"
      }
   }
}
```

How to do this with Node.js, Express 4 and is there another library for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your own middleware that parses the incoming form data using body-parser's `urlencoded()` and turns it into a structured JSON:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

function setDeepValue(path, obj, value) {
  const tokens = path.split('.');
  const last = tokens.pop();
  for (const token of tokens) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(token)) {
      obj[token] = {};
    }
    obj = obj[token];
  }
  obj[last] = value;
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(), function(req, res, next) {
  let obj = {};
  for (const key in req.body) {
    setDeepValue(key, obj, req.body[key]);
  }
  req.body = obj;
  next();
});

app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code you are posting to a create route.

So in express you need to create that route

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  console.log('----- MY BODY -----')
  console.log(req.body)
  // do something more clever
  res.send('We posted to this route')
})
```

First we require express, then we require body-parser and finally initialize our express app.

We then use the json middlewere of body-parser to parse the body so that we can easily access it in our handler.

We then define a route to `'/create'` that accepts posts request (remember that your form is posting to this location).

All that our handler does is to console.log the body of the request, and then shows the message *We posted to this route*

Comment: The form data is sent to the server with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and I don't think the JSON parser handles that.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. I updated the code to include encoded bodies.

Answer (score -2):

Follow this guide repository specially created to guide freshers [nodejs-frontend-sample-for-freshers](https://github.com/navinbisht1992/nodejs-frontend-sample)

**EDIT:**

You can use Ajax call to submit form this will also help in **Single Page Application**

Client-side JS:

```
function submit() {
    // JavaScript uses `id` to fetch value
    let email               = $("#email").val(),
        name                = $("#name").val(),
        city                = $("#city").val(),
        land                = $("#land").val();

    // Can validate each field here and show error like:
    if ( validateEmail(email) ) {
        $("#emailError").addClass("hide");
    } else {
        $("#emailError").removeClass("hide");
        return;
    }

    // form request data, doing this will get you data in correct form at NodeJs API
    let data = {
        user: {
            email,
            name,
            address: {
                city,
                land
            }
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/create",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": data
    })
    .then( result => {
        // On success empty all the input fields.
        $("#email").val('');
        $("#name").val('');
        $("#city").val('');
        $("#land").val('');

        // Message to notify success submition
        alert("Successfully added user.");
        return;
    })
    .catch( err => {
        // Notify in case some error occured
        alert("An error occured.");
        return;
    });
}

// Validate Email based upon pattern
function validateEmail (email) {
    if ( email && email.match(/^([A-z0-9_.]{2,})([@]{1})([A-z]{1,})([.]{1})([A-z.]{1,})*$/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="text" id="email" />
    <span id="emailError" class="hide error">Valid Email Required</span>
    <input type="text" id="city" />
    <input type="text" id="land" />
    <p onclick="submit()">Submit</p>
</form>
```

Would recommend you to use `cors.js` too like:

```
const cors = require('cors');

// Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(cors());
```

You can get object in two ways:

1: Using no extra module something like this

```
app.post('/create', function (request, response, next) {

    let body       = [];

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        body       = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        console.log(body); // Your object
        request.body = body;  // Store object in request again

        next();
    });
}, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // This will have your object 
});
```

2. Using `body-parser` with `express`:

```

```
// configure the app to use bodyParser() to extract body from request.
// parse urlencoded types to JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }));

// parse an HTML body into a string
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));

app.post('/create', function (request, response, next) {
    console.log(request.body);  // `body-parser did what I did earlier`
});
```

```

Comment: Neither of these approaches solve the problem of turning an object `{"user.name":"foo", "user.email": "foo@bar.com"}` into `{"user": {"name":"foo", "email":"foo@bar.com"}}`.

Comment: That is how JSON object is `var x = {"user": {"name": "foo", "email": "bar"}` when you will do `x.user.name` this will give you `'foo'`. Check JSON object notation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript  And this does solve your problem, you just don't know about JSON.

Comment: Please, read the discussion carefully before jumping to a judgement like this. I was pointing out that your code *does not* convert the incoming form data into a JSON object with the expected structure.

Comment: share your code so can have a better view what's going wrong

Comment: I used your proposed code to create this express app: https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/b7e80cc847079cc779007e584a3b3185. After submitting the form data to the server, `request.body` has an incorrect structure. It should be `{ "user": { "address": { "city": "foo" } } }` but instead it looks like this: `{ "user.address.city": "foo" }`.

Comment: To be clear, @dterencio wants the structure of `request.body` to be `{ "user": { "address": { "city": "foo" } } }`. This answer doesn't take care of that.

Comment: got it your answer provides whole solution Thanks @PetrBroz